# sprintf add special character in C

Tags: c, linux, debian, codeblocks

can anyone help me. I'm trying to create a folder, but when I use `sprintf`, it concatenates at the end special characters like `OUUUU`, how can I fix it?
there is an image (link below) where you can see the directory variable that has `"/home/mia"` and the buffer has `"mkdir/home/miaOUUUU"`

Any suggestions?

i'm using codeblocks in debian...

[image: Sorry, don't know how to copy text from coeblocks]

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q3KKBbyDjA8_dfwKT54_OT_5QeREIz7k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of C code; paste the text into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should post the code in the body of the question, with copy+paste from your IDE and one extra indentation level (select the code and type Alt-K for that), not as a link to a bitmap, it is very rude.

`directorio` is not null terminated. You must declare it with one extra element as `char directorio[i + 1];` and make sure to initialize `directorio[i]` to `'\0'`.

The `memset` is useless since you overwrite the whole buffer in the subsequent `for` loop. Do this instead:

```
char directorio[i + 1];
memcpy(directorio, path, i);
directorio[i] = '\0';
DIRP *dirp = opendir(directorio);
if (dirp == NULL) {
    ...
} else {
    // do not forget to close the directory
    closedir(dirp);
}
```

Also note that you should create directories from the root directory to the final path, and you should handle the spurious case of an existing file with the same name as one of the directories along the path.